# how to auto enable bluetooth base on the android simple code?

Tags: android

This is the code that I'm trying to use. Could you please tell me what the problem is with it??

My code:

```
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
          if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

          }else{
               mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
          } ;
    } {
        if (mChatService == null) setupChat();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What problem are you having? My guess is that you need to add both the BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions to your app.

Note that the preferred solution is to use an intent to prompt is the user wants to enable bluetooth:

```
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableIntent);
```

Also note that the call to `enable` is asynchronous, it will return immediately and enable Bluetooth in the background. Hence Bluetooth may not actually be enabled yet, it may still be getting ready. See also [the Android guidelines on Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

**EDIT** added disable/wait/enable/wait sample code

This is sample code for requesting Bluetooth to turn off, then waiting for it to turn on. It **must** be run in a separate thread and **not** in the UI thread. It would be possible to encapsulate this in a `Runnable` Class which sets a (preferably `volatile`) flag to to true if it completes successfully.

**Note:**  this sample code is known to have issues on some older devices that do not allow diable/enable to be called from user applications.

```
            BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().disable();
            while (BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isEnabled())
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100L);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    // unexpected interruption while disabling Bluetooth
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // restore interrupted flag
                    return;
                }
            }
            // disabled, re-enabling Bluetooth
            BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable();
            while (!BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isEnabled())
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100L);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    // unexpected interruption while enabling bluetooth
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // restore interrupted flag
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Comment: how to auto turn on the bluetooth without request the user base on the simple code?

Comment: @DanielTang as I said, make sure you have both the `BLUETOOTH` and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permissions in your manifest, then you can call ` mBluetoothAdapter.enable()`, however if you want to use bluetooth immediately you'll need to wait until `mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()` is true, it may take a few seconds.

Comment: i sure i have both the BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions. do you mean i can cancel the mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() to enable the bluetooth very quick??

Comment: Correct, bluetooth will take as long as it takes to disable or enable once you request it. I have added sample code for this wait in the solution above.

Comment: thx of your code, it's auto turn on the bluetooth on the phone, but i still had error when i connect other bluetooth device.

Comment: what is the remote device? What is the bluetooth protocol? What is the error? Maybe start a new question to track that.

Comment: i connect the other PC bluetooth device by the secure mode. i don't know what error is it, the eclipse only say source no find. but if i turn on the bluetooth on the phonr before i turn the apps, is work. if i didn't do that, let the apps auto turn on the bluetooth device i had this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
        } 
        else(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
             mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); 
        }
    }
}
```